# Cannot enable CDN for azure media services

Tags: azure, video-streaming, storage, cdn, azure-media-services

I have an azure media services account with streaming units. When I try to enable CDN, it gives me an error.

```
Failed to enable CDN for StreamingEndpoint 'default'!

CORRELATION IDSclientNotification-59ed507b-c014-4093-8604-243ccef1901e
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The streaming endpoint must be in a stopped state. Once the CDN gets enabled, you can start the streaming endpoint. Please note that it could take up to 90 min for the Azure CDN integration to get enabled.

Comment: Oh I actually contacted microsoft tech support, the problem was that there was a bug in the azure CDN integration code for Australia South East storages. They have fixed the bug now.